# FirebaseSimpleLogin not working in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8, winjs, firebase, windows-8.1, facebook-winjs-sdk

I asked a [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828632/is-it-possible-to-use-firebase-with-a-windows-8-app) about if it was possible to use Firebase in a Windows 8/WinJS app. @MichaelLehenbauer told me that I just needed to add the following line to my code in order to fix a bug in firebase.js:

```
Firebase.INTERNAL.forceWebSockets()
```

This worked great and allowed me to read and write to my Firebase. However, now I am trying to get auth working in Windows 8 and running into many issues. I am trying to use the Facebook login but when I call `auth.login("facebook")`, my app loses focus and a new tab in the modern Internet Explorer app (not the desktop app) is opened with the typical Facebook login prompt. If I put in my credentials and hit login, nothing happens. I need to go back to my app but then it fires up a new IE tab and the process starts again. Instead of opening a new IE tab, Firebase should internally be opening an in-app dialog like seen in the top image [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/create-login-screen-in-metro-style-application/).

So, since I couldn't get the Firebase Facebook login working in WinJS, I tried doing the Facebook login myself and then create Firebase users using the email/password auth. However, when I run:

```
auth.login("password", {
    email: "me@example.com",
    password: "password"
});
```

I get the following warning (which is the same warning I received from firebase.js befoore Michael suggested to me to force web sockets):

```
APPHOST9601: Can’t load <https://auth.firebase.com/auth/firebase?&firebase=[my_firebase]&transport=jsonp&email=me%40example.com&password=password&callback=FirebaseSimpleLogin._callbacks._firebaseXDR13889674277557>. An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.
```

I'm not sure if this is another web sockets issue or not, but it looks like FirebaseSimpleLogin is just not working very well in Windows 8 apps. Are there any workarounds to these problems? Even better, is there any plan to provide full support out of the box with Windows 8?

Comment: [Engineer at Firebase] Would you mind reaching out to me directly at rob at firebase.com? I'd be happy to help debug this issue and get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 is now supported out of the box with Firebase Simple Login.