# Is it possible to use firebase for making windows 10 mobile and xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, firebase, windows-10-mobile

I have read the post
[Is it possible to use Firebase with a Windows 8 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828632/is-it-possible-to-use-firebase-with-a-windows-8-app)
but i don't know anything about windows phone app development so i want to know that is it possible to make windows 10 mobile and xamarin apps with firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty good wrapper api called firesharp you can use in any windows app inc phone, look it up in nuget console

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't support windows phone apps yet.

As per firebase you can only create three type of projects,

1. Android
2. iOS
3. Web